# Parsing a genbank file format with biopython's SeqIO

Tags: python, parsing, biopython

I'm trying to parse a protein `genbank` file format, Here's an example file (`example.protein.gpff`)

```
LOCUS       NP_001346895             208 aa            linear   PRI 20-JAN-2018
DEFINITION  intercellular adhesion molecule 2 precursor [Cercocebus atys].
ACCESSION   NP_001346895
VERSION     NP_001346895.1
DBSOURCE    REFSEQ: accession NM_001359966.1
KEYWORDS    RefSeq.
SOURCE      Cercocebus atys (sooty mangabey)
  ORGANISM  Cercocebus atys
            Eukaryota; Metazoa; Chordata; Craniata; Vertebrata; Euteleostomi;
            Mammalia; Eutheria; Euarchontoglires; Primates; Haplorrhini;
            Catarrhini; Cercopithecidae; Cercopithecinae; Cercocebus.
REFERENCE   1  (residues 1 to 208)
  AUTHORS   Palesch D, Bosinger SE, Tharp GK, Vanderford TH, Paiardini M,
            Chahroudi A, Johnson ZP, Kirchhoff F, Hahn BH, Norgren RB, Patel
            NB, Sodora DL, Dawoud RA, Stewart CB, Seepo SM, Harris RA, Liu Y,
            Raveendran M, Han Y, English A, Thomas GWC, Hahn MW, Pipes L, Mason
            CE, Muzny DM, Gibbs RA, Sauter D, Worley K, Rogers J and Silvestri
            G.
  TITLE     Sooty mangabey genome sequence provides insight into AIDS
            resistance in a natural SIV host
  JOURNAL   Nature 553 (7686), 77-81 (2018)
   PUBMED   29300007
COMMENT     VALIDATED REFSEQ: This record has undergone validation or
            preliminary review. The reference sequence was derived from
            KY308194.1.

            ##Evidence-Data-START##
            Transcript exon combination :: KY308194.1 [ECO:0000332]
            RNAseq introns              :: single sample supports all introns
                                           SAMN02045730, SAMN03085078
                                           [ECO:0000348]
            ##Evidence-Data-END##
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..208
                     /organism="Cercocebus atys"
                     /db_xref="taxon:9531"
     Protein         1..208
                     /product="intercellular adhesion molecule 2 precursor"
                     /calculated_mol_wt=21138
     sig_peptide     1..19
                     /inference="COORDINATES: ab initio prediction:SignalP:4.0"
                     /calculated_mol_wt=1999
     Region          24..109
                     /region_name="ICAM_N"
                     /note="Intercellular adhesion molecule (ICAM), N-terminal
                     domain; pfam03921"
                     /db_xref="CDD:252248"
     Region          112..>167
                     /region_name="Ig"
                     /note="Immunoglobulin domain; cl11960"
                     /db_xref="CDD:325142"
     CDS             1..208
                     /gene="ICAM2"
                     /coded_by="NM_001359966.1:1..627"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:105590766"
ORIGIN
        1 mssfgfgtlt malfalvccs gsdekafevh mrleklivkp kesfevncst tcnqpevggl
       61 etslnkilll eqtqwkhyli snishdtvlw chftcsgkqk smssnvsvyq pprqvfltlq
      121 ptwvavgksf tiecrvpave pldsltlsll rgsetlhsqt frkaapalpv lrelgmkfiq
      181 lcprrglagt mppsrpwcpa athwsqgc
//
LOCUS       NP_001280013             406 aa            linear   MAM 22-JAN-2018
DEFINITION  26S proteasome regulatory subunit 8 [Dasypus novemcinctus].
ACCESSION   NP_001280013 XP_004456848
VERSION     NP_001280013.1
DBSOURCE    REFSEQ: accession NM_001293084.1
KEYWORDS    RefSeq.
SOURCE      Dasypus novemcinctus (nine-banded armadillo)
  ORGANISM  Dasypus novemcinctus
            Eukaryota; Metazoa; Chordata; Craniata; Vertebrata; Euteleostomi;
            Mammalia; Eutheria; Xenarthra; Cingulata; Dasypodidae; Dasypus.
COMMENT     VALIDATED REFSEQ: This record has undergone validation or
            preliminary review. The reference sequence was derived from
            AAGV03083693.1.
            On May 28, 2014 this sequence version replaced XP_004456848.1.

            Sequence Note: The RefSeq transcript and protein were derived from
            genomic sequence to make the sequence consistent with the reference
            genome assembly. The genomic coordinates used for the transcript
            record were based on alignments.

            ##Evidence-Data-START##
            RNAseq introns :: mixed/partial sample support SAMN00668203,
                              SAMN00744121 [ECO:0000350]
            ##Evidence-Data-END##
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..406
                     /organism="Dasypus novemcinctus"
                     /db_xref="taxon:9361"
     Protein         1..406
                     /product="26S proteasome regulatory subunit 8"
                     /calculated_mol_wt=45495
     Region          4..404
                     /region_name="RPT1"
                     /note="ATP-dependent 26S proteasome regulatory subunit
                     [Posttranslational modification, protein turnover,
                     chaperones]; COG1222"
                     /db_xref="CDD:224143"
     CDS             1..406
                     /gene="PSMC5"
                     /coded_by="NM_001293084.1:1..1221"
                     /db_xref="GeneID:101445299"
ORIGIN
        1 maldgpeqme leegkagsgl rqyylskiee lqlivndksq nlrrlqaqrn elnakvrllr
       61 eelqllqeqg syvgevvram dkkkvlvkvh pegkfvvdvd knidindvtp ncrvalrnds
      121 ytlhkilpnk vdplvslmmv ekvpdstyem iggldkqike ikevielpvk hpelfealgi
      181 aqpkgvllyg ppgtgktlla ravahhtdct firvsgselv qkfigegarm vrelfvmare
      241 hapsiifmde idsigssrle ggsggdsevq rtmlellnql dgfeatknik vimatnridi
      301 ldsallrpgr idrkiefppp neearldilk ihsrkmnltr ginlrkiael mpgasgaevk
      361 gvcteagmya lrerrvhvtq edfemavakv mqkdseknms ikklwk
//
```

The format has repeating `record`s (separated by `//`), where each `record` is a protein. Each `record` has several sections among them a `FEATURES` section with several fixed fields, such as `source`, `CDS`, and `Region`, with values that refer to information specific to that `record`.

I'm interested in using `biopython`'s `SeqIO` to parse this file into a `dataframe` which lists for each record ID, the values of its `gene`, `db_xref`, and `coded_by` from its `CDS` field, the `organism` and `db_xref` values from its `source` field, and `db_xref` value from its `Region` field. Except for the `Regions` field, which may appear several times in the `FEATURES` section of a `record`, the `CDS` and `source` fields appear only once in the `FEATURES` section of a `record`.

My unsuccessful attempt so far looks like this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
filename = "example.protein.gpff"
for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, "genbank"):
  for feature in record.features:
    if feature.type == "CDS":
      symbol = feature.qualifiers.get("gene", ["???"])[0]
      gene_id = feature.qualifiers.get("db_xref", ["???"])[0]
      gene_id = re.sub('GeneID:', '', gene_id)
      transcript_id = feature.qualifiers.get("coded_by", ["???"])[0]
      transcript_id = re.sub(':.*', '', transcript_id)
      if feature.type == "source":
        species_name = feature.qualifiers.get("organism", ["???"])[0]
        species_id = feature.qualifiers.get("db_xref", ["???"])[0]
        species_id = re.sub('taxon:', '', species_id)
      if feature.type == "Region":
        cdd_id = feature.qualifiers.get("db_xref", ["???"])[0]
        cdd_id = re.sub('CDD:', '', cdd_id)
      print("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" % (record.id, cdd_id, transcript_id, symbol, gene_id, species_name, species_id))
```

The resulting `dataframe` I'd like to obtain (for the `example.protein.gpff` above) is:

```
    record_id  CDS_coded_by   CDS_db_xref CDS_gene              source_organism source_db_xref Region_db_xref
1 NP_001346895  NM_001359966.1:1..627 GeneID:105590766  ICAM2      Cercocebus atys taxon:9531 CDD:252248
2 NP_001346895  NM_001359966.1:1..627 GeneID:105590766  ICAM2      Cercocebus atys taxon:9531 CDD:325142
3 NP_001280013 NM_001293084.1:1..1221 GeneID:101445299  PSMC5 Dasypus novemcinctus taxon:9361 CDD:224143
```

Comment: Curious, can you convert the gpff to xml? If so, you can use DOM methods to parse.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [*Genebank-parser*](https://github.com/aminehd/Genebank-parser) library. It accepts a genebank filename and the batch size; `next_batch` yields as many number of records as batch_size specifies.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the easiest way to deal with this file format is to convert it to a `JSON` format (for example, using [Bio](https://www.bioinfo.help/bio-json.html)), and then read it with various `JSON` parsers (like the [rjson](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html) package in `R`, which parses a `JSON` file to a `list` of `record`s)